# react-router-dom and Typescript: A type annotation is necessary.ts(2742)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm trying to route a class component with react-router-dom.
When I use `withRouter` on my component, I get this error:

> The inferred type of 'default' cannot be named without a reference to
> `'react-transition-group/node_modules/@types/react'`. This is likely not
> portable. A type annotation is necessary. ts(2742)

Example code:

```
/* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
import React from "react";
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

type Params = {
  value: string;
};

type Props = RouteComponentProps<Params>;

class ClassComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return <span>Value: {match.params.value}</span>;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ClassComponent);
```

What do I need to annotate and how?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I'm not able to reproduce your issue. I don't get any ts errors in codesandbox. Please try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - your error references `react-transition-group` so it seems likely that this module is somehow involved, but none of your code references it. Perhaps you still need to install that [library's types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-transition-group)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I'm working on a MRE now. The types for react-transition-group were already installed.

Comment: Update: I was unable to create a MRE, the error did not occur in codesandbox as well.

Comment: Update: I re-downloaded all dependencies and the problem seems to have solved itself.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I fixed this by deleting the node_modules folder and re-downloading all dependencies.

Comment: this did not work for me.